# Send password in Drupal 7 user registration mail after admin approval

Tags: drupal-7

I am creating a site in Drupal 7. I am using user registration through admin approval. After admin approval I want to send user password in user mail, but going username and only "Your password" static text.

Anybody can help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](http://drupal.org/node/1165126) and more precisely the comment [#16](http://drupal.org/node/1165126#comment-5593768):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 * */
function modulename_token_info() {
    $info['tokens']['user']['password'] = array(
    'name' => t('Password'),
    'description' => t('The password by the user'),
    );
return $info;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 * */
function modulename_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
    $replacements = array();
    $url_options = array('absolute' => TRUE);
    if (isset($options['language'])) {
        $url_options['language'] = $options['language'];
    }
    if ($type == 'user' && !empty($data['user'])) {
        $account = $data['user'];
        foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
            switch ($name) {
                case 'password':
                    $replacements[$original] = $account->password;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $replacements;
}
```

After that, in your `/admin/config/people/accounts` you'll find the token for the new user's password [user:password]

Comment: When admin activate user account after approval then i want to send his/her password in email. Otherwise this module is working for me.
http://drupal.org/project/rpt